# How do i generate a nativescript plugin tarball with the new workflow?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to build a plugin around a native iOS/Android SDK. I would like to know to finally generate a my-plugin.tgz file so that I can use it locally without publishing it.
I have done this with Nativescript 6.x, but I would like to know how to do this with the new workflow in Nativescript 7.x.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the `build` command from `npm start`, you will get a `dist` directory with a structure like this

```
dist
  |- packages
        |- your-plugin-name
```

`cd` into the `packages` directory and run `npm pack your-plugin-name` and you should get the .tgz file in the same directory which you can use in locally

Comment: I am getting an error while doing this:   npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nativescript-myplugin - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'nativescript-myplugin@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Answer (score 0):

The latest seed has the following instructions

> Publish to NPM When you have everything ready to publish: Bump the version number in src/package.json
> Go to publish and execute publish.sh (run chmod +x *.sh if the file isn't executable)
> If you just want to create a package, go to publish folder and execute pack.sh. The package will be created in publish/package folder.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed#publish-to-npm